# I want only the footer tag fit in the screen, not the whole body

Tags: html, css

I am having problem, again, with footer tag. I want this part to fit in the whole screen. But not the other part of the body. Thats why I didn't put margin:0; to body elements.

I tried to set margin:0 to footer, but it didn't work (marked in the picture). How can I fix this problem.

my css file of footer

```
footer{
 padding: 5vw;
 margin:0px;
 background-color: #DCEDC8;
 color: black;
 font-size: 4vw;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCczY.jpg![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCczY.jpg!%5B) footer doesn't fit to the screen properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dblej.jpg)

Comment: Please post the image you mentioned in your question. It doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Are you sure its not the body margin/padding that gives footer this behaviour

Comment: Your footer is for sure inside another element, which probably is causing the padding or margin. 
Please provide the full code.

Comment: The body margin is set to default. I didn't change the margin of body, cause I don't want the whole body being fit to the screen. I only want footer part to fit the screen. fooyer is inside the body tag, obviously. How can I  apply margin none to footer only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you currently have is that `body` has a margin set by default, and so any element inside the body tag (including your footer!) will also be affected by that margin.

To fix this, you can apply `margin: 0` to body and place all of your content into a container div (which has some margin).

Then, put your footer outside of the container and set its margin to 0 as well.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: #9f9f9f;
}

footer {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ff5555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      Your content goes here. Notice that there is a margin surrounding this div.
    </div>
    <footer>
      Your footer goes here. Notice that there is no margin surrounding this footer.
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```